# How can I export a list such as ['apple', 'carrots', 'mango'] into one column in excel with openpyxl? In Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to be able to create a column in excel with a list in python using openpyxl. I tried using append(row) but it seems that that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Please at least show us the code you tried (even if it didn't work), so we can start from there. [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56085256/edit) and include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write each entry in the list as a list item to the worksheet:

```
import openpyxl

l = ['apple', 'carrots', 'mango']

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

col = 'C' # Set the desired column

for n, i in enumerate(l, 1):
    ws[col+str(n)] = i

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Should produce expected output as desired column:

[image: output in Excel]

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I wanted to do.